# What does the value mean when assigning non-ascii character to a python built-in string?

Tags: python, string, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I am recently studying something related to encoding and I am confused about the following:

See if I have

```
a = "哈"  ## whatever non-ascii char is fine
a[0] ## = "\xe5"
a[1] ## = "\x93"
a[2] ## = "\x88"
```

`len(a)` would be 3, and each of the value would be "\xe5", "\x93", and "\x88"

I understand that if I do:

```
a.decode("utf-8") ## = u"\u54c8"
```

It will become a unicode string, and the code point would be "\u54c8".
The question is: what encoding method does the built-in python string use?
Why a[0] not be "\x54" and a[1] not be "\xc8" so that they together are "54c8"?

I guess the encoding in built-in python str should not be utf-8 because the right utf-8 code point should be "\u54c8". Is that right?

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: sry i did not make it clear . It is python 2.7.12. @rdegges

Comment: For more info on utf8, including code that manually decodes it, please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/38653062/4014959

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTF-8 and Unicode are not the same thing. Unicode is an abstract mapping of integer values to characters; UTF-8 is *one* particular way of representing those integers as a sequence of bytes. `\xe5\x93\x88` is the three-byte UTF-8 encoding of the integer 0x54c8, which cannot be represented by a single byte.

The default encoding in Python 2 was ISO-8859, but was changed to UTF-8 in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

The result of pasting a non-ascii character into the interpreter like that is dependent on your terminal encoding.  It's likely (from seeing your data) that it's a utf-8 encoding on your terminal.

```
a = "哈"
```

When you evaluate that line of code in Python 2 interactive interpreter, you'll create a bytestring object that *is already encoded*.

To get a text object from it, you'll have to decode the data using:

```
a.decode(encoding)
```

It helps to always think of a `str` object as *bytes* and a `unicode` object as *text*.

**There is no simple relationship between the codepoint and the utf-8 encoded bytes.**  The relationship that *is* simple is that

```
u'哈' == u'\u54c8' == unichr(21704)
```

Think of the codepoint as just an index in a big table, which you use to lookup the character at that index.  The above equality just shows that 哈 is the character at codepoint 21704 (because in hex, 0x54c8 is 21704).

If you want to know the relationship between a codepoint (21704) and the UTF bytes (the \xe5 and \x93 stuff), I already wrote a long answer about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29225126/674039).  You can read it if you're interested to learn how to encode/decode UTF by hand.